# AttributeError: 'textChunker' object has no attribute 'print_chunks'

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I run the below code, it gives me the following error:

```
printchunks = text_Chunker.print_chunks(input_data,chunk_size)
AttributeError: 'textChunker' object has no attribute 'print_chunks'
```

Why is it giving me this error?

This is my code. It has a `textChunker` class, which I call in the main function.

Why is the function `print_chunks` not defined?

```
import numpy as np
from nltk.corpus import brown

# Split the input text into chunks, where
# each chunk contains N words
class textChunker:

    def __init__(self, input_data='', chunk_size=0):

        self.input_data = input_data
        self.chunk_size = chunk_size

    def chunker(self,input_data, N):
        input_words = input_data.split(' ')
        output = []

        cur_chunk = []
        count = 0
        for word in input_words:
            cur_chunk.append(word)
            count += 1
            if count == N:
                output.append(' '.join(cur_chunk))
                count, cur_chunk = 0, []

        output.append(' '.join(cur_chunk))

        return output

        def print_chunks(self,input_data,chunk_size):
            import chunker
            chunks = chunker(input_data, chunk_size)
            print('\nNumber of text chunks =', len(chunks), '\n')
            for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
                print('Chunk', i + 1, '==>', chunk[:50])

if __name__=='__main__':

    input_data = ' '.join(brown.words()[:12000])
    chunk_size = 700

    text_Chunker=textChunker()
    printchunks =text_Chunker.print_chunks(input_data,chunk_size)
```

Comment: StackOverflow is much more helpful when you specify what you're trying to do and what you want help with. More specifically. Show what you've tried already.

Answer (score 0):

You need to unindent your `print_chunks` function, so it is in line with your other functions in the `textChunker` class.

EDIT: other edits have been made besides the unindentation (see edit history) by the asker to make the code work.

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
from nltk.corpus import brown

# Split the input text into chunks, where
# each chunk contains N words
class textChunker:

    def __init__(self, input_data='', chunk_size=0):

        self.input_data = input_data
        self.chunk_size = chunk_size

    def chunker(self,input_data, N):
        input_words = input_data.split(' ')
        output = []

        cur_chunk = []
        count = 0
        for word in input_words:
            cur_chunk.append(word)
            count += 1
            if count == N:
                output.append(' '.join(cur_chunk))
                count, cur_chunk = 0, []

        output.append(' '.join(cur_chunk))

        return output

    def print_chunks(self,input_data,chunk_size):
        import textChunker
        chunks = self.chunker(input_data, chunk_size)
        print('\nNumber of text chunks =', len(chunks), '\n')
        for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
            print('Chunk', i + 1, '==>', chunk[:50])

if __name__=='__main__':

    input_data = ' '.join(brown.words()[:12000])
    chunk_size = 700

    text_Chunker=textChunker()
    printchunks =text_Chunker.print_chunks(input_data,chunk_size)
    print(sent_tokenize(input_data))
```

Comment: thank you, but its gives me this error: 
  
  printchunks =text_Chunker.print_chunks(input_data,chunk_size)
      chunks = chunker(input_data, chunk_size)
 TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: Sorry, I don't know enough about `chunker` to help

Comment: i fixed it by add self before chunker

Comment: @Nabilkabha great! Please edit my answer to include this.